# Unable to log messages while running a Flask app

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, flask

I am trying to tie Flask's logger to a FileHandler, so I can save custom log messages to a file. Anytime I try to log a message when a POST requests hits `foo`, nothing happens, at all. How can I work around this?

```
import logging
from logging import FileHandler
from time import strftime

from flask import Flask, Response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/foo', methods=['POST'])
def bar():
    app.logger.info('post request')
    ...
        return Response(), 200

if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_date = strftime('%d_%m_%Y')
    handler = FileHandler(f'./log/{file_date}.log')
    handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    app.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    app.logger.addHandler(handler)
    app.run()
```